# Regular expression in SSIS

Tags: regex, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have this data in a column:

```
<b>Dummy Alerts: </b>3/3Alerts have been addressed&#10; Question Alert: Have you had problems or are your volumes lower than normal?  " +
                "Yes Alert is closed on 01/09/2018 at 01:08 PM&#10; Question Alert: Have you been drinking more fluid? " +
                " Yes Alert is closed on 10/09/2019 at 01:08 PM&#10;&#10;Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry). " +
                "TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time. " +
                "Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.  Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN."
```

and other similar types of records.

I want to select only these text and insert into new column:-

```
 Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry).
            TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time.
            Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN.
```

I would like to use Regular expression in SSIS

Comment: SSIS is most likely the wrong tool for this. What other tools are you familiar with? Also... please actually try something first. Have you created an SSIS package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS does not support Regex out of the box.
You can definitely use [RegexClean](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/RegexClean-Transformation.aspx) and [Regular Expression](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Regular-Expression-Transformation.aspx) transformations from Darren Green. Or - you can do whatever needed in your custom Script transformation, like described in [this sample](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/) employing C# and .Net.